# How to get the size of a loaded library on java application in the runtime

Tags: java, linux, jvm

Kindly I need help to get the size of a specific loaded library in a running Java Application.

In details, I'm running a Java application though JVM on Linux. While I'm trying to get the memory consumption of a specific library that is being loaded during the App initialization.

So I'm using something like the following:

```java
public class Test 
{
     static
     { 
        System.loadLibrary("Tested_Lib");
     }

     public int register () { ......}
     public int unregister () { ......}
}
```

So what I'm asking for:

1. Is loading the library that way means that the total library size will be loaded to the JVM address space?
2. How to measure the memory consumption of "Tested_Lib" in the running time?

I have tried the following:

```java
        System.gc();
        usedMemoryBefore = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
 
        System.loadLibrary("Tested_Lib");

        usedMemoryAfter = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
        libSizeInRam = (usedMemoryAfter - usedMemoryBefore)/KILOBYTE;
```

while the output was not reasonable at all regarding the expected size of the lib.

Comment: You may be able to read the size of the actual library file, but that won’t tell you what memory allocations that library has performed.  I doubt there is any way to do that.

Comment: There is no "total library size". Please define what exactly you want to measure.

Comment: Why the heck it has `embedded-linux` tag?

Comment: @VGR, For the Memory allocation I think there are some dynamic analysis tools specified for monitoring this in the run time like Valgrind-Massif tool I think, but how can I get the actual lib size that you have referenced to ?

Comment: @apangin, I need to measure the memory consumption of this Lib is it clear ?, the Idea that I'm a beginner in the jvm and linux memories staff so I'm not able to understand how the lib is going to be allocated to the memory after loading it, and how we can get its size in the runtime

Comment: No: "memory consumption" is ambiguous: it can be virtual memory, resident set size, Java heap size, etc. It's unclear whether you want to count memory mapped sections of the library image or dynamically allocated memory or both. If this library depends on two other libraries, one of which has been loaded before your library and the other one after, which of them would you like to count? You see, the question is not as simple as it may look. Please start by explaining your originial problem (i.e. *why* do you want to measure), this will help us give you the *right* answer, not a random one.

Comment: You may get some memory stats of the process by reading [`/proc/self/statm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) pseudofile.

Comment: @apangin, I got what you mean, Okay let me give you a brief about the Idea, The issue that I may have some non functional requirements in my project that state as following:  "Tested_library shouldn't exceed x ram usage during the runtime.", Hence I started to search for a mechanism that could give me such an information. As far as I understand, the consumed ram memory of the lib is separated to the size of the loaded library itself in the memory "static size", in addition to the heab size " which has dynamically allocated memory during runtime."

Comment: Measure RSS of the process without library loaded and with the library loaded. The difference will be the approximation of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Runtime.totalMemory() and freeMemory() is not very precise. It doesn't consider what other threads of the Java process or your library may be doing. Calling System.gc() is just a suggestion to the JVM to do garbage collection. There is no guarantee it will execute, and when it does it only cleans the heap memory pool, which is only the memory pools the JVM uses for object instances. Whatever your library is doing will not be inside the heap, unless it uses JNI to manipulate Java objects.

IF you only want to know the memory the shared library file uses in memory in Linux you should refer to Linux-specific answers like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116327/loading-of-shared-libraries-and-ram-usage. This is not a Java question.